# Keeping unique records in Access query, based on two columns

Tags: ms-access

I have a list of events that organizations attended. The list has duplicates because one organization might have had multiple sign-ups.

So I need to keep only one record, based on Profile ID (First column) and Event name. 
So if profile ID=1 has 3 records where they attended Event=y, I need to keep only one of these and delete the other two rows. See the image:
[query screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZaL1.png)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT eliminates duplicates. Make sure to have only the fields defining a duplicate in the query.
eg if there were for example a date field for the event, you should leave it out in the query.